# VBA Excel: Retrieve/display email using Gmail API on excel

Tags: vba, excel, email, gmail-api

I research regarding retrieving or displaying emails from gmail without using outlook and it led me here on using Gmail API. I'm confused because I don't have idea on how to solve my problem.

Here's the code:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Gmail"
' Setup client and authenticator (cached between requests)
Private pGmailClient As WebClient
Private Property Get GmailClient() As WebClient
If pGmailClient Is Nothing Then
    ' Create client with base url that is appended to all requests
    Set pGmailClient = New WebClient
    pGmailClient.BaseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/"

    ' Use the pre-made GoogleAuthenticator found in authenticators/ folder
    ' - Automatically uses Google's OAuth approach including login screen
    ' - Get API client id and secret from https://console.developers.google.com/
    ' - https://github.com/timhall/Excel-REST/wiki/Google-APIs for more info
    Dim Auth As New GoogleAuthenticator
    Auth.Setup CStr(Credentials.Values("Google")("id")), CStr(Credentials.Values("Google")("secret"))
    Auth.AddScope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
    Auth.Login
    Set pGmailClient.Authenticator = Auth
End If

Set GmailClient = pGmailClient
End Property

' Load messages for inbox
Function LoadInbox() As Collection
Set LoadInbox = New Collection

' Create inbox request with userId and querystring for inbox label
Dim Request As New WebRequest
Request.Resource = "users/{userId}/messages"
Request.AddUrlSegment "userId", "me"
Request.AddQuerystringParam "q", "label:inbox"

Dim Response As WebResponse
Set Response = GmailClient.Execute(Request)

If Response.StatusCode = WebStatusCode.Ok Then
    Dim MessageInfo As Dictionary
    Dim Message As Dictionary

    For Each MessageInfo In Response.Data("messages")
        ' Load full messages for each id
        Set Message = LoadMessage(MessageInfo("id"))
        If Not Message Is Nothing Then
            LoadInbox.Add Message
        End If
    Next MessageInfo
End If
End Function

' Load message details
Function LoadMessage(MessageId As String) As Dictionary
Dim Request As New WebRequest
Request.Resource = "users/{userId}/messages/{messageId}"
Request.AddUrlSegment "userId", "me"
Request.AddUrlSegment "messageId", MessageId

Dim Response As WebResponse
Set Response = GmailClient.Execute(Request)

If Response.StatusCode = WebStatusCode.Ok Then
    Set LoadMessage = New Dictionary

    ' Pull out relevant parts of message (from, to, and subject from headers)
    LoadMessage.Add "snippet", Response.Data("snippet")

    Dim Header As Dictionary
    For Each Header In Response.Data("payload")("headers")
        Select Case Header("name")
        Case "From"
            LoadMessage.Add "from", Header("value")
        Case "To"
            LoadMessage.Add "to", Header("value")
        Case "Subject"
            LoadMessage.Add "subject", Header("value")
        End Select
    Next Header
End If
End Function

Sub Test()
Dim Message As Dictionary
For Each Message In LoadInbox
    Debug.Print "From: " & Message("from") & ", Subject: " & Message("subject")
    Debug.Print Message("snippet") & vbNewLine
Next Message
End Sub
```

I'm using the blank file from this [GitHub Link](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) that enables this code above. I was stuck on this error: 
 [image: user-defined type declared]

Still I don't have the idea what's the output of this API because it's my first time using this one. I have my id and secret already from **Gmail API** i just removed it from the code. I guess it was really hard if I don't have someone I can do brainstorming regarding on this matter.

Hoping someone have encountered this problem or anyone is interested. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use `Microsoft Outlook`? I havent read this [LINK](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjnj7uXw_LXAhUD2LwKHZ9JBLsQFghYMAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.trezor.io%2Fwhy-you-should-never-use-google-authenticator-again-e166d09d4324&usg=AOvVaw1K3-SXeokK0CfhQGvwPeKt) Please check this before using it

Comment: @nishitdey There is an account login on the outlook and I want to use a different account and excluding outlook on the process.

Comment: Looks like there are multiple class modules you need to install, located on the github page in the `authenticators` folder like [this one](VBA-Web/authenticators/GoogleAuthenticator.cls).  This is going to be a complex way to not use Outlook (which _can_ have multiple accounts associated, including gmail.)

Comment: @ashleedawg The company that I was working limit every person not to mess with outlook even we can associate multiple accounts. Now to bypass that rule, the only thing that maybe "solve" the problem is by using gmail api. I used the blank file on the github page that has authenticators already but still no progress.

Comment: If the company is locking down Outlook (and behind a firewall I assume?) I don't think you'll be able to sneak past their security setup my using a more complicated API.  _Maybe_ POP3 mail could work but I doubt it.

Comment: @ashleedawg Have any other idea on how to fetch gmail's inbox? I can already send an email using cdo but fetching from using it was impossible.

Comment: Perhaps via POP3 with a third-party add-in like this one: https://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail (which I've used before).  The free version is only _slightly_ annoying.  :-)

Comment: @ashleedawg Working in a company where everything is limited is too much to handle. Installing that one was impossible. Damn policy :-/